# Css background-image не отображается

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Я получаю с сервера html строку и вставляю в компоненте через `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, да это не безопасно, я знаю.

Проблема в том, что в html у некоторых элементов есть тег style со свойством `background-image`, но картинки нет. Причем в консоли показана, что ее ничто не перекрывает и при наведении на ссылку, которая опять же в консоли - появляется картинка. ТО есть ссылка рабочая

Из-за чего такое странное поведение?

```js
< li
key = {
  message.name + Math.random()
}
dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {
  {
    __html: message.mess
  }
}
/>
```

```html
<!-- ПРИМЕР html с сервера-->

<a href="https://vk.comvideo261429253_456239577?list=0ac80163fc3da5011f" data-video="261429253_456239577" data-list="0ac80163fc3da5011f" data-duration="739" aria-label="Видео &quot;Перелезаем через заборы в костюме с Алексеем Щербаковым&quot; ФИНАЛЬНЫЙ ВЫПУСК Ток-шоу! + доп. материалы длительностью 12 минут 19 секунд "
  onclick="return showInlineVideo(&quot;261429253_456239577&quot;, &quot;0ac80163fc3da5011f&quot;, {&quot;autoplay&quot;:1,&quot;module&quot;:&quot;&quot;}, event, this);" style="width: 347px;height: 195px;background-image: url(https://sun9-39.userapi.com/YtOQaHjxeNi_QWRBkiXtzBHxc0EoLgnsVkdZHw/Xvjm5OXRI04.jpg) !important;"
  class="page_post_thumb_wrap image_cover page_post_thumb_video page_post_thumb_last_column page_post_thumb_last_row">
  <div class="page_post_video_play_inline"></div>
  <div class="video_thumb_label"><span class="video_thumb_label_item">YouTube</span><span class="video_thumb_label_item">12:19</span></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я добавил `display.block` для ссылки и картинка появилась

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите ответ надлежащим образом - сейчас он больше похож на комментарий.